# How to use AWS Sagemaker based on usage and not per hour basis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I want to create an inference endpoint using AWS Sagemaker LLM deployed model via a ml.g5.2x large instance type. The inference is used via AWS Lambda and API gateway. While the services are based on usage, Im getting charged per hour for using the machine instance - ml.g5.2x that hosts the LLM model, despite being not used frequently. Is there a way to set up the instance such that I get charged for using it and not on per hour basis? I am new to AWS Sagemaker and request for advice on setting up the usage requirement.

I tried followed this tutorial:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/serverless-endpoints.html

But would this solve the issue?

Thanks in advance